# Caching problem with .htm on MVC3 view.  

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that loads external HTML into an iframe.  I don't know if the iframe is compounding the issue, but even when the content of the file that the iframe loads has long been replaced with a newer, working content, Chrome still loads the ghost of the older, broken HTML file into the iframe.  Fortunately my files are named with GUID's, so I could fix this problem by simply renaming the file, but I would like to get to the bottom of this.  I am using the build in web server, not IIS.

**MY EXCUSE FOR IFRAMES:**
My admin end user will be uploading HTML published from Excel, along with all it's gory styling.  Writing import code is way to complex at this stage.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has told me to stay the hell away from iframes yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than renaming the file what I usually do is append a querystring to all static data on my page with some kind of key generated on the server side.

This way you can ensure your JS, CSS, HTML and any other static content types are re-loaded when you change them.

Another thing you *can* do is have the iframe point to something that acts as a proxy for the static page and returns it. Probably a bit overkill for what you're trying to do and my preference would be the querystring method.

As for getting to the bottom of the problem, there are so commonly known caching issues with iframes, one of them being the caching of the actual url (hence the second option above).

Comment: Thanks @Jamie.  Fortunatey, in production every change to file content will mean a new upload and so a new filename.